# Guzzle HTTP POST returns cURL error 7: Failed to connect to <url> port 8083: Connection refused

Tags: laravel, guzzle

When trying to send POST request through Guzzle it returns error from the title.

Confusing part of this problem is that same POST request but on other hosting is working without a problem.

This is what code looks like:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://capcap.milovanovic.net:8083/weborder', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'AutoAssignTablePrefix' => 'W',
            'ExternalId' => $currentOrder->id,
            'Customer' => $customer,
            "ComputerName" => "POS-DOSTAVA",
            "Items" => $itemsForAPI,
            "Payments" => [
                [
                    "PaymentTypeId" => $paymentID,
                    "Amount" => $totalAmount
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

It is very strange because same block of code works on different hosting, so does anyone maybe have a idea what would be the problem?

Comment: Show how you instantiate `$client`.

Comment: Hello Mahdi, simple like this: $client = new Client(); and on top of the page: use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Comment: I've tried the exact code and it was Ok for me!

Comment: @MahdiJedari Could it be that it has to do something with hosting? Because for me exact same code works on different hosting. Also works on postman

Comment: Check it by postman. The issue is probably out of Guzzle

Comment: @MahdiJedari I will try to reinstall guzzle package then

Comment: The url maybe unreachable for the IP that you use. It could be banned by the host.